# Serious MySQL query performance issues after adding condition

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, amazon-aurora

My problem is that I have a mysql query that runs really fast (0.3 seconds) even though it has a large amount of left joins and a few conditions on the joined columns, but when I add one more condition the query takes upwards of 180 seconds! I understand that the condition means the execution plan has to adjust to pull all potential records first and then apply the condition in a loop, but what's weird to me is that the fast query without the additional condition only returns 16 rows, and even just wrapping the query with the condition on the outer query takes a crazy amount of time when you would think it would only just add an additional loop through 16 rows...

If it matters this is using Amazon Aurora serverless which should align with mysql 5.7

Here's what the query looks like. You can see the additional condition is commented out. (The general table structure of the DB itself cannot change currently so please refrain from suggesting a full database restructuring)

```sql
select 
    e1.entityId as _id,
    v1.Value,
    v2.Value
    v3.Value,
    v4.Value,
    v5.Value,
    v6.Value,
    v7.Value,
    v8.Value,
    v9.Value,
    v10.Value,
    v11.Value,
    v12.Value 
from entity e1
left join val as v1 on (v1.entityId = e1.entityId and v1.attributeId = 1189) 
left join val as v2 on (v2.entityId = e1.entityId and v2.attributeId = 1190) 

left join entity as e2 on e2.entityId = (select entityId from entity where code = v1.Value and type = 88 limit 1) 
left join val as v3 on (v3.entityId = e2.entityId and v3.attributeId = 507) 
left join val as v4 on (v4.entityId = e2.entityId and v4.attributeId = 522) 
left join val as v5 on (v5.entityId = e2.entityId and v5.attributeId = 558)
left join val as v6 on (v6.entityId = e2.entityId and v6.attributeId = 516)
left join val as v7 on (v7.entityId = e2.entityId and v7.attributeId = 518)
left join val as v8 on (v8.entityId = e2.entityId and v8.attributeId = 1384) 
left join val as v9 on (v9.entityId = e2.entityId and v9.attributeId = 659) 
left join val as v10 on (v10.entityId = e2.entityId and v10.attributeId = 519) 
left join val as v11 on (v11.entityId = e2.entityId and v11.attributeId = 1614)

left join entity as e3 on e3.entityId = (select entityId from entity where code = v9.Value and type = 97 limit 1) 
left join val as v12 on (v12.entityId = e3.entityId and v12.attributeId = 661)

where e1.type = 154
and v2.Value = 'foo'
and v5.Value = 'bar'
and v10.Value = 'foo2'
-- and v11`.Value = 'bar2'

order by v3.Value asc;
```

And wrapping that in something like this still takes forever...

```sql
select * 
from (
    <query from above>
) sub
where sub.v11 = 'bar2';
```

query execution plan with the condition commented out (fast)
[image: query execution plan with the condition commented out (fast)]

[image]

query execution plan with the condition included (slow)
[image: query execution plan with the condition included (slow)]

[image]

I'm going to fiddle around with indexing on the "entity" tables to improve the execution plan regardless which will likely help... but can someone explain what's going on here and what I should be looking at in the execution plan that would indicate such bad performance? And why wrapping the fast query in a subquery so that the outer query should only loop over 16 rows takes a really long time?

EDIT: I noticed in the slow query that the far left execution is using a non-unique key lookup (which is on val.entityId) for "68e9145e-43eb-4581-9727-4212be41bef5" (v11)  instead of the unique key lookup the rest are using (which is a composite index on entityId,attributeId). I presume this might be part of the issue, but why can't it use the the composite index there like it does for the rest?

PS: For now since we know the result set will be small, we are implementing that last condition server side with a filter on the result set in our nodeJS server.

Here's the results of "SHOW CREATE TABLE entity" and "SHOW CREATE TABLE val"

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `entityId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  PRIMARY KEY (`entityId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UID` (`UID`),
  KEY `IX_Entity_Type` (`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Entities_Types` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `entityTypes` (`typeId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=296138 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `val` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `attributeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entityId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UID` (`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_val_entityId_attributeId` (`entityId`,`attributeId`),
  KEY `IX_val_attributeId` (`attributeId`),
  KEY `IX_val_entityId` (`entityId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2325375 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: this looks more like a very bad design

Comment: Those UUIDs make it hard to read!

Comment: `please refrain from discussing the structure of the DB` Our work here is complete :-(

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I updated the query to be much easier to read. The query is generally auto-generated and not usually intended to be human readable.

Comment: @Strawberry I should've worded that better. I meant it as "the general structure is not mine nor can it be changed, so please do not suggest that it should be done completely differently". I am simply asking for an explanation as to why the structure/design as is gets the performance hit in the specific scenario of adding an additional column condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I would hope to see these composite indexes:

```
`val`: (entityId, attributeId)   -- order is not critical
```

Alas, because `code` is `LONGTEXT`, this is not possible for `entity`: `INDEX(type, code, entityId)`.  Hence this will not be very efficient:

```
        SELECT  entityId
            from  entity
            where  code = v9.Value
              and  type = 97
            limit  1
```

I see `LIMIT` with an `ORDER BY` -- do you care which value you get?

Probably that would be better written as

```
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM entity
                WHERE entityID = e3.entityID
                  AND code     = v9.Value
                  AND type = 97 )
```

(Are you sure about the mixture of `e3` and `v9`?)

Wrapping...

This forces the `LEFT JOIN` to become `JOIN`.  And it gets rid of the then inner `ORDER BY`.

Then the Optimizer probably decides it is best to start with `68e9145e-43eb-4581-9727-4212be41bef5`, which I call `val AS v11`:

```
JOIN val AS v11 ON (v11.entityId = e2.id
             and  v11.attributeId = 1614)
             AND  v11.Value = 'bar2')
```

If this is an EAV table, then all it does is verify that [, 1514] has value 'bar2'.  This does not seem like a sensible test.

in addition to my former recommendation.

I would prefer `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

**EAV**

Assuming `val` is a traditional EAV table, this would probably be much better:

```
CREATE TABLE `val` (
  `attributeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entityId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  PRIMARY KEY(`entityId`,`attributeId`),
  KEY `IX_val_attributeId` (`attributeId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2325375 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The two IDs have no practical use (unless I am missing something).  If you are forced to use them because of a framework, that is unfortunate.  Promoting (entityId, attributeId) to be the PK makes fetching `value` a little faster.

There is no useful way to include a `LONGTEXT` in any index, so some of my previous suggestions need changing.

Comment: Yes this is an EAV schema. I added the explain spreadsheet and table creation queries to the original question. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Is it a good idea to index the value in an EAV schema, as per your last suggestion? And also I'm still confused as to why it couldn't use the (attributeID,entityID) index on v11 instead of deciding to use just the (attributeID) index.

Comment: @razorcat - If both INDEX(a,b) and INDEX(a) exist, sometimes the Optimizer uses INDEX(a) when the other would be better.  Meanwhile, INDEX(a,b) satisfies any query that only uses the "a" part.

Comment: @razorcat - Thanks for editing my Answer.  I made a few more edits, plus added a discussion of the EAV table `val`.  If `LONGTEXT` could be replaced by only `VARCHAR(767)` (or smaller), some better indexes could be added.

Comment: I knew INDEX(a) didn't need to be there due to the recent addition of INDEX(a,b), but I figured the optimizer would be smart enough to use the better one in that case since both a and b were queried on. I removed INDEX(recordID) on my val table and that actually fixed it! 

On the response regarding the longtext vs varchar(767), We have some very large text stored in val, so that's unfortunately not an option for us. But it does make sense! Maybe I could add a "shortText" val table to the EAV schema...

Comment: The UID column in our val tables are useless and I'll be removing them soon. But the val "ID" column is used as foreign keys for things like data logs, which I guess could be refactored to instead link by entityId,attributeID pair...

Comment: And eventually those entity joins with the "limit 1" will be moot, as a future refactor will allow us to instead query directly on the PK entityId. IE `left join entity as e2 on e2.EntityID = v1.Value` which should help a bit as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please share any documentation or discussions regarding the mysql optimizer sometimes deciding to use INDEX(a) when INDEX(a,b) exists when querying on a and b? I'd like to know more about what could cause that to happen...

Comment: I started a new question, since that's a different topic I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127484/mysql-optimizer-not-using-the-best-index

Comment: @razorcat - Adding another column to EAV complicates the code, probably not worth it.  `ID` - why would some other table be reaching for it _in that case_?

Comment: @razorcat - and Re:  Removing `INDEX(recordID)` -- I learned this by surprise not nong ago; one would think that the Optimizer would be smarter.  I have not found an official document, but the Optimizer is probably saying "neither (a) nor (a,b) is perfect, so I will use the smaller index".  I experimented with the when writing this section of "find nearest":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#bounding_box