# MySQL optimizer not using the best index?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, amazon-aurora

This is a continuation from [Serious MySQL query performance issues after adding condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114871/serious-mysql-query-performance-issues-after-adding-condition), specifically about something that was pointed out in the answer.

We have an EAV data model, and adding more than 3 conditions on joined columns causes the query to go from 0.3 seconds to 65+ seconds. The cause appears to be because mysql's optimizer starts using non-optimal indexes, and I want to understand why.

The query in question is the following...

```sql
select 
    e1.RecordID as _id,
    v1.Value,
    v2.Value,
    v3.Value,
    v4.Value,
    v5.Value,
    v6.Value,
    v7.Value,
    v8.Value,
    v9.Value,
    v10.Value,
    v11.Value,
    v12.Value
    
from Record e1
left join TextValue as v1 on (e1.RecordID = v1.RecordID and v1.PropertyID = 1189)
left join TextValue as v2 on (e1.RecordID = v2.RecordID and v2.PropertyID = 1190)

left join Record as e2 on e2.RecordID = v1.Value
left join TextValue as v3 on (v3.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v3.PropertyID = 507)
left join TextValue as v4 on (v4.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v4.PropertyID = 522)
left join TextValue as v5 on (v5.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v5.PropertyID = 558)
left join TextValue as v6 on (v6.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v6.PropertyID = 516)
left join TextValue as v7 on (v7.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v7.PropertyID = 518)
left join TextValue as v8 on (v8.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v8.PropertyID = 1384)
left join TextValue as v9 on (v9.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v9.PropertyID = 659)
left join TextValue as v10 on (v10.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v10.PropertyID = 519)
left join TextValue as v11 on (v11.RecordID = e2.RecordID and v11.PropertyID = 1614)

left join Record as e3 on e3.RecordID = v9.Value
left join TextValue as v12 on (v12.RecordID = e3.RecordID and v12.PropertyID = 661)

where e1.RecordTypeID = 154
and v2.Value = 'asdfgh'
and v5.Value = 'sdfghj'
and v10.Value = 'dfghjk'
and v11.Value = 'fghjkl'
```

The tables looks like the following.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `textvalue` (
  `TextValueID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `PropertyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RecordID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TextValueID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UID` (`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_textvalue_RecordID_PropertyID` (`RecordID`,`PropertyID`),
  KEY `IX_TextValue_PropertyID` (`PropertyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2326526 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `RecordID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `RecordTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Code` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecordID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UID` (`UID`),
  KEY `IX_Record_RecordTypeID` (`RecordTypeID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Records_RecordTypes` FOREIGN KEY (`RecordTypeID`) REFERENCES `recordtype` (`RecordTypeID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=296389 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The execution plan for the query looks like such and executing the query took 65 seconds. Note the index chosen for the v11 table...
[image]

HOWEVER if I change all of the TextValue joins to `left Join Textvalue as X FORCE INDEX (idx_textvalue_RecordID_PropertyID)` I get the following execution plan and the query takes 0.1-0.3 seconds...
[image]

What's going on here that would explain why the mysql optimizer chooses to use the IX_TextValue_PropertyID index when the idx_textvalue_RecordID_PropertyID index appears to clearly be better in this scenario?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Record` (so we can see `e1`)